# Añadir lenguaje Español a un DateBox en JQuery Mobile

Tags: android, jquery, date, jquery-mobile

Tengo un datebox hecho con jquery mobile en un programa android. La cosa es que necesito que se muestre tanto en español como en inglés, dependiendo del idioma del teléfono pero no llego a tener claro como hacerlo.

Tengo un div donde declaro el datebox

```
<input  id="mydate" type="date" readonly="readonly" onchange="control()" data-role="datebox"
        data-options='{"mode":"calbox","useFocus":true,"disabled": true}' >
```

Y tengo un fichero js donde esta el datebox llamado `jquery.mobile.datebox.js`

Supuse que era añadir la parte de español, que sería como lo que pongo abajo.

```
useLang: 'en',
    lang: {
        'en' : {
            setDateButtonLabel: 'Set Date',
            setTimeButtonLabel: 'Set Time',
            setDurationButtonLabel: 'Set Duration',
            calTodayButtonLabel: 'Jump to Today',
            titleDateDialogLabel: 'Set Date',
            titleTimeDialogLabel: 'Set Time',
            daysOfWeek: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
            daysOfWeekShort: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
            monthsOfYear: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            monthsOfYearShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            durationLabel: ['Days', 'Hours', 'Minutes', 'Seconds'],
            durationDays: ['Day', 'Days'],
            timeFormat: 24,
            headerFormat: '%A, %B %-d, %Y',
            tooltip: 'Open Date Picker',
            nextMonth: 'Next Month',
            prevMonth: 'Previous Month',
            dateFieldOrder: ['m', 'd', 'y'],
            timeFieldOrder: ['h', 'i', 'a'],
            slideFieldOrder: ['y', 'm', 'd'],
            dateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
            useArabicIndic: false,
            isRTL: false,
            calStartDay: 0,
            clearButton: 'Clear'
        }

    }
```

La cosa es que veo que por defecto el useLang esta puesto con 'en' (por lo que no hace ni caso al español) y no se como hacerlo... alguien sabe?
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No tienes que especificar cada una de las [traducciones](http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/doc/3-2-locale/) a menos que quieras customizar las palabras usadas en ellas. Puedes encontrar una lista de todos los lenguajes soportados [aquí](http://cdn.jtsage.com/jtsage-datebox/i18n/). Incluso puedes modificar uno de ellos a tu gusto y usar tu propia versión ya que para incluirlo solo tienes que poner un script con esta forma

```
<script src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/jtsage-datebox/i18n/jtsage-datebox.i18n.es-ES.utf8.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Te dejo un demo del control en español.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/jtsage-datebox/latest/jtsage-datebox.jqm.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jtsage.com/jtsage-datebox/latest/jtsage-datebox.jqm.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/jtsage-datebox/i18n/jtsage-datebox.i18n.es-ES.utf8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input id="mydate" type="date" readonly="readonly" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"calbox","useFocus":true,"disabled": true}'>
```

Ahora que si quieres escoger entre múltiples lenguajes vas a tener que cargarlos y especificar el lenguaje deseado por código. Esto es necesario pues si lo especificas por `data-options` el input será procesado inmediatamente con un valor fijo.

Recuerda que el fichero [`jtsage-datebox.lang.utf8.min.js`](http://cdn.jtsage.com/jtsage-datebox/i18n/jtsage-datebox.lang.utf8.min.js) contiene **TODOS** los lenguajes.

La forma de obtener el lenguaje actual es mediante la propiedad [navigator.languaje](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language)

Creo que este demo puede ayudarte

```js
$(function() {
  var lenguajesSoportados = ['en', 'es-ES'];

  var lenguajeActual =
    lenguajesSoportados.indexOf(window.navigator.language) !== -1 ? window.navigator.language : 'en';

  $('#mydate').datebox({
    "mode": "calbox",
    "useFocus": true,
    "disabled": true,
    "useLang": lenguajeActual
  });;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/jtsage-datebox/latest/jtsage-datebox.jqm.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jtsage.com/jtsage-datebox/latest/jtsage-datebox.jqm.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/jtsage-datebox/i18n/jtsage-datebox.lang.utf8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input id="mydate" type="text" readonly="readonly">
```

Por último si quieres soportar todos los lenguajes puedes usar la opción

```
"useLang": window.navigator.language
```

directamente en tu código. Es importante que el tipo del input sea del tipo `"text"` cuando inicializas los controles de esta forma de acuerdo a la [documentación](http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/doc/3-0-first-datebox/).

Comment: Hola , gracias por tu amplia respuesta, pero no hay manera, si lo hago como dices, no sale el calendario en el móvil. Y si añado <script src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/jtsage-datebox/i18n/jtsage-datebox.lang.utf8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> no hace nada... esto me tiene desesperada... otra cosa si añado lo otros script y css que dices mi diseño se estropea. Gracias nuevamente por tu respuesta

Comment: Puede ser porque mi version es la 1.0.1-2012022700 ???.
Gracias

Comment: @Renata Como ves en mi respuesta el snippet de código funciona bien. Si tienes una versión vieja de jQuery Mobile es muy probable que no te funcione de conjunto con el plugin así que deberías intentar usar la ultima versión de los dos frameworks. Es la unica forma de garantizar la compatibilidad.